# Django And Elasticsearch

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am evaluating the opportunity to include some elasticSearch indexes in our Django Backend, I reviewed so far three django apps:

- django-elasticsearch-dsl
- elasticsearch-django
- django-haystack

So far, I can't tell if there is such a package not needing to replicate content of the indexes in the django DB, from what I read, it seems like we have to have some standard Relational DB ORM objects attached to each indexes.

If I am right, that then implies the data duplication, and potentially a huge one in our case.
Is there a way with the mentioned packages to avoid this objects duplication? Or did I misread the whole thing and it's not actually duplicating data?

Thanks for your insights!
Marc